# How can i update information in a table each time i launch my console app?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I would like to update a table each time the console app is launched. My problem is that _exe is empty and I don’t know how to go about assigning it the value that is in DbContext. Can someone guide me in the right path, I’m new to this.

```cs
    class Program 

    {
        private static readonly ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaireRepository _exe;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.atlas.intranet/v1/produits/");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("ayantdroits");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaire[]>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    var perimetreProduits = readTask.Result;

                    foreach (var perimetreProduit in perimetreProduits)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\"louiseProduitId\":{0}, \"startDate\":{1}, \"endDate\":{2}", perimetreProduit.LouiseProduitId, perimetreProduit.StartDate, perimetreProduit.EndDate);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("after pull");

                    if (perimetreProduits != null)
                    {
                        _exe.DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE [Acq.ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaire]");
                        _exe.DbContext.SaveChanges();

                        if (_exe.DbContext.ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaire == null)
                        {
                            foreach (var perimetreProduit in perimetreProduits)
                            {
                                _exe.DbContext.ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaire.Add(perimetreProduit);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `if (_exe.DbContext.ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaire == null)` You check its null, then you `Add` to it. That won't end well.

Comment: @mjwills is there a reason to check if its null if I am about to delete wtv there is in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared it, but not assigned anything to it. At some point you need to create it:

```
_exe = new ExecutionPerimetreProduitNonLineaireRepository();
```

You also need to check that the ConnectionString is set in the config file of the app.